# jQuery why can I select the id using dot notation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I have the code below unexpectedly working and I want to know why.

Basically, I am clicking on a button to change the value of an input text field.
The input has an id of 'here' but no name or class. Yet, I am able to change its value by using dot notation `here.value`

Note that I am using a simple dot notation instead of a jQuery selector, bracket notation, or `getElementById(id)` method. As far as I know, this should NOT work.

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mhz5pwmh/2/)

```
<input id="here" readonly>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click">
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').on('click', function() {
    // why does this dot notation work for id?
    here.value = 'you clicked on the button';
    // should be:
    // $('#here').val('you clicked on the button');
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Here's the part of the current HTML spec that addresses this: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#named-access-on-the-window-object

Comment: Thank you for the answer! (redirecting link)